# How can I export ubuntu terminal's profile in another computers?

Tags: 14.04, 15.04, gnome-terminal

I use this command to save my current terminal profile settings:

```
gconftool-2 --dump '/apps/gnome-terminal' > gnome-terminal-conf.xml
```

And this other command to load profile settings:

```
gconftool-2 --load gnome-terminal-conf.xml
```

But it does not work. I have Ubuntu 14.04LTS and I would like to export my current terminal profile to other machines that run on Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04 and 15.10, all this with a Bash script.

Comment: It may well be the case that some settings simply won't work in newer versions.

Comment: ok i see, so you have any recommendation ?

Comment: You can import the settings into 14.04 but not into 15.04 and 15.10.

Comment: What settings are you trying to keep? Is it your macro's (in that case simply copy the content of you ~/.bashrc file (or at least the parts that you have changed))

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried backing up the folder `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal`? You can  even try = but it's not the best solution - copying `/home/kostasz/.gconf/apps/gconf-editor.

Answer (score 0):

So, the `xml` file alone will not work from what I understand. It has to point to or work with a file and location like `~/.profile` as in my /home folder
 perhaps I am wrong?, but I remember, I had to have both from my back ups to restore my system
James Niland